# A difficulty in understanding a special case of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I do not understand how this result is a special case of theorem 9.1, could anyone explain this for me please?

[image]

This is theorem 9.1:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "result" it mentions is "Every finite-dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis". Because you take a basis and apply Gram-Schmidt to it.

Comment: But Gram scmidt also say that it can make an infinite basis set also orthonormal .....right?

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt process doesn't care if the list of linearly independent vectors is finite or infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Take an inner product space with a basis, then the basis vectors are linearly independent, Gram-Schimdt tells you that you can make this set of vectors orthonormal (and still linearly independent), hence every inner product space has an orthonormal basis.

Comment: But Gram scmidt also say that it can make an infinite basis set also orthonormal .....right?

Comment: I think it is for finite dimensional spaces...